# Rebase method intercept, completely overriding method

Tags: java, kotlin, byte-buddy

I'm trying to do some runtime code changing using ByteBuddy. The problem that I've run into is that when I try to rebase a method to add an intercept call at the end, the entire method gets replaced and there isn't any $original() method declared and called after.

This is the code I'm using for the proper transformation

```
ByteBuddy()
    .rebase(clazz)
     .method(ElementMatchers.named("onEnable"))
     .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(TestInjector()))
     .make()
     .saveIn(dataFolder)
```

clazz and dataFolder are defined above this and aren't the source of the problem.

This is the signature of the injector method:

`public void intercept(@This JavaPlugin pl)`

In analyzing the code it outputs, the class is identical to pre-transformation, but all the code that *was* getting called in the onEnable method has been removed, and replaced with the single method delegate. Is there a way, using a method like this, for me to keep the existing method body, but add a delegate call to the head of the method?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to invoke the original method, you can chain a SuperMethodCall to the interceptor using "andThen". This instructs Byte Buddy to invoke the original method after the delegation call.